# Converting float to binary using IEEE754 standard

Tags: binary, floating-point, elixir

How to convert 32-bits float binary using IEEE754 standard in Elixir.

Converting integer is possible by using `Integer.to_string/2` and passing base 2 as the second option

```
iex> Integer.to_string(5, 2)
"101"
```

but there is no such function for Float module and only `Float.to_string/1` exists

Answer (score 1):

```
iex> <<-2.90::float-32>>
<<192, 57, 153, 154>>
```

In case you need to convert it to hex

```
<<-2.1::float-32>> |> Base.encode16
"C0066666"
```

[more reading](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1) about `<<>>` macro

Comment: You answered your own question wrong?   I  mean are you trying to convert to binary or some other radix?

Comment: `<<192, 57, 153, 154>>` is a binary and it's collection of bytes, so from this format you may convert it to base 2 or 16.